# Redux useSelector with id field

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-hooks

I need your advice on filtering data with a selector. Suppose I have the following entities in my application. 1 organization has multiple devices which look the following in my state shape:

```
state {
   devices: {
       byId: [ 1 { name: device1 } ]
   }
   organizations: {
       byId: [ 
          1 { name: org1, devices: [1,2,3] } 
       ]
   }
}
```

Now I want to filter the devices inside the organization. This is something that I want to do with a selector. My selector looks like the following:

```
const selectDevice = (id: any) => (state: State) => state.devices.byId[id]


export const selectOrganizationDevices = (id: number) => (state: State) => {
    const organization = state.organizations.byId[id] || []
    return organization.devices.map(id => selectDevice(id)(state))
}
```

This should be working fine but my selector got called before I have dispatched the data from redux. I suppose that there's something wrong with my reducer or the component I've created.

My reducer looks like this:

```
return produce(state, draftState => {
        switch (action.type) {
            ...
            case OrganizationActionTypes.FETCH_DEVICES_SUCCESS: {
                draftState.byId = action.payload.entities.organizations
                draftState.allIds = Object.keys(action.payload.entities.organizations)
                draftState.loading = false
                break;
            }
            ...
            default: {
                return state
            }
        }
    })
```

My functional component looks like the following:

```
function Devices() {
    const dispatch = useDispatch();
    const devices = useSelector(selectOrganizationDevices(1))

    useEffect(() => {
        dispatch(fetchOrganizationDevices(1))
    }, [])

    const columns = []
    
    return (
        <Layout headerName={"Devices"}>
             <Table dataSource={devices} columns={columns}/>
        </Layout>
    )
}
```

The error I get now is `organization.devices is undefined` which says that the array of devices in the state is empty. It seems that useSelector is called before dispatch. How can I prevent redux of doing this? Or what should be changed in my code?

Comment: try `return organization.devices ? organization.devices.map(id => selectDevice(id)(state)): []`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the `useEffect` hook runs *after* the first render.  `useSelector` will run *during* the first render.  So, your component code needs to safely handle the case where that data doesn't exist yet.

Also, don't put a hardcoded array/object literal in a selector like that, as it will be a new reference every time and force your component to re-render every time an action is dispatched.  Either extract that to a constant outside of the selector, or use a memoization library like Reselect to create the selector.

Finally, you should be using [our official Redux Toolkit package](https://redux-toolkit.js.org), which includes utilities to simplify several common Redux use cases, including store setup, defining reducers, immutable update logic, and even creating entire "slices" of state at once.  It also has a new `createEntityAdapter` API that helps you manage normalized state in the store.

Comment: I didn't know about the `createEntityAdapter` API. Thanks a lot for your support helping me out!